# Python: Accessing dictionary from txt file and adding new data to it and then storing this updted dict back in txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a text file in exact format given bellow,

```
 {'one': 'a', 'two': 'b', 'three': 'c'}
```

I want to take that dictionary in a variable say dict1.
My program generates new key value pairs, if the new generated key is is not present in dict1 then I want to add this new key in dict1.
finally I want to update txt file with this updated dictionary.

I know how to add key value pairs to a dict but I am not able to read that dictionary from txt file into a dictionary type of variable.

can anybody help plz ?

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array is how to read a text file

Comment: "I am not able to read that dictionary from txt file into a dictionary type of variable" <- why, what's the problem?

Comment: Here's a hint: use [`ast.literal_eval`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: alternatively, store and load as json.

Comment: How was this file written in the first place? You need to know the rules used for serialization before you can figure out how to parse it again.

Comment: initially the file is handwritten, any newly encountered key later I want to append to that dictionary..

What is good practice should I use dictionary or a json to store those key value pairs? I just want to store key value pairs in a text file, this text file will be given as input to another program which will generate some keys if key already not present in txt file then I need to append this new key with some value to the text file..

Comment: SO whats good practice? should I store in the form of json or a dictionary?

Comment: That's up to you, really - if you want this to be editable without being loaded into your code, then I'd pick a format like JSON. It also makes it easier to process beyond just Python. If this isn't going to be of much use beyond your work, then it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code works for me:

```
import ast

dict_file = open("dict.txt", "r")
dict_string = dict_file.readline().strip()
dict_file.close()

d = ast.literal_eval(dict_string)
print d["one"]

#change your dictionary e.g:
d["foo"] = "bar"

f = open("dict.txt", "w")
f.write(str(d))
f.close()
```

It simply reads the string from the file and creates a dictionary using the "ast.literal_eval". You can then commit changes to the dictionary, convert it to a string and write it to the txt file.

You could alternatively use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: after I have updated the dict how to store updated dict to that dict.txt file?

Comment: @Ritzor I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If your text file is named `foo.txt`, then

```
import json

with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

new_key = 'foo'
if new_key not in d:
    d[new_key] = 'bar'
    with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d, f)
```

Comment: If his file is formatted as he's shown, your code's going to throw an exception because of the single quotes. He'll need `"` everywhere to make it JSON-compatible.

Comment: OP didn't show us JSON so this can't really be considered an answer.